# Iterative scraping

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I have a set of a few thousand pages in my localhost, named article1.html, article2.html and so on. My objective is to scrape all these pages individually and dump their contents to a JSON file with the same respective names(the contents of article1.html would be in article1.json, article2.html in article2.json and so on). I'm attempting to run through these pages with a simple loop and pass in the count integer to the parse function but it doesn't seem to be working. My code looks like this:

```
class scraper0Spider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "scraper0"
allowed_domains = ["localhost"]
start_urls = [
   "http://localhost/"
]

def start_requests(self):
     for i in xrange(1,1084):
        yield scrapy.Request("http://localhost/article%s.html" %i, self.parse)

def parse(self,response):
    #grab relevant content and do other stuff, all the content will be in the variable fullstring

    with open("article%s.json" %i, 'w') as f:
        #f.write(stringjson)
        json.dump(fullstring, f)
```

Attempting to use a global variable has not helped either. How should I pass i into the parse function?

Comment: `...it doesn't seem to be working` what does it mean ?

Comment: My bad for being too vague there. Attempting to pass it in directly as an additional argument was interpreted as the HTTP method instead and using a global variable resulted in all iterations of the loop having the same value for i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the *`i` variable is defined in the scope of the `start_requests`.*

If you want it to be available in `parse()`, pass it inside [`meta`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions):

```
class scraper0Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scraper0"
    allowed_domains = ["localhost"]
    start_urls = [
       "http://localhost/"
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
         for i in xrange(1, 1084):
            yield scrapy.Request("http://localhost/article%s.html" % i, self.parse, meta={"index": i})

    def parse(self, response):
        with open("article%s.json" % response.meta["index"], 'w') as f:
            json.dump(fullstring, f)
```

Comment: Didn't realise the answer was in there all along, thanks!